# Add a second return value to a wrapped function without losing backward compatibility

Tags: python, flask, refactoring

In a third-party framework sources response function is wrapped as following:

```
from flask import Response

def wrap_func(func):
    def add_context(*args, **kwargs):
        output_value = func(*args, **kwargs)

        return Response(
            output_value
        )

    return add_context
```

And developer can use this decorator to make a custom function something like an entry point:

```
@wrap_function
def hello():
    return '<b>Hello</b>'
```

Framework creates a response and send it, this functionality is hidden "under the hood".

And now I need to set some `Response` parameters such as cookies from my function `hello`. As it seems to be impossible without the wrapper changes, I decided to contribute to the framework.

My very first though was to return an optional value from wrapped function (`hello`) with response parameters and then parse it inside `add_context`. Note, that backward compatibility matters, "old-styled" functions should work as well as "new", with response parameters. So, alongside with `hello`, wrapper would have to support functions like this:

```
@wrap_function
def ping():
    return '<b>Hello</b>', {'cookies': [('te', 'st')]}
```

But as for me it's definitely a hack job. Maybe there are some best practices to implement such change or even better approach to modify return of the wrapped function without losing compatibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I decided to make it simple and flexible way. Now the wrapped function should return a markdown as usual or `Response` object with initialized with markdown body. And then, inside the wrapper, different actions performed based on `isinstance`.

```
from flask import Response

def wrap_func(func):
    def add_context(*args, **kwargs):
        output_value = func(*args, **kwargs)

        if isinstance(output_value, Response):
            return output_value
        else:
            return Response(
                output_value
            )

    return add_context
```

Although outside this minimal example wrapper needs to modify response body, it works after creating `CustomResponse` based on `Response` and redefining needed actions.